# How to get a count of documents that contain keys from another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am building a personal blog

I have two collections; posts and comment

posts look like this

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('5d7bf67d30bb02db73fd491d'),
    'title': 'Comments',
    'post_author': ObjectId('5d7008ce6d6a577820420467'),
    'content': "There is a comment",
    'date_posted': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 20, 5, 17, 367000)
}
```

comments look like this

```
}    '_id': ObjectId('5d7c9717c9fc4f7b8e19e906'), 
     'user': ObjectId('5d7008ce6d6a577820420467'), 
     'post_id': ObjectId('5d7b5aee0de3faa4cc8a1dc0'), 
     'title': 'is this going to get super nested?',
     'content': 'this is getting weird',
     'date_posted': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 14, 7, 30, 31, 587000)
}
```

I am trying to get a count of comments for each post

I have been trying to loop through all the posts, and use count to get the number of comments each post has, like so;

```
def comment_count():
    posts = mongo.db.posts.find().sort("_id", -1)
    for post in posts:
        post_id = post['_id']
        count = mongo.db.comment.count({'post_id': post_id})
        return count
```

My template looks like this

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class="posts z-depth-2">
            <div class="post-card">
                <span class="post-title"><a href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post._id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></span>
                {{ comment_count }}
                {% if post.date_posted %}
                <span class="post-date">{{ post.date_posted.strftime("%d %b %Y") }}</span>
                {% endif %}
                <hr>
            </div>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I call comment_count from my template to display the number of comments for each post, it returns 6 for all posts, regardless of the actual number of comments. I would expect it to actually give a correct count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). The operation you need to run consists of a pipeline on the `post` collection that does a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to the `comments` collection and create an extra field that returns the count of the items in the array the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline step produces.

Consider running the following aggregate operation:

```
def posts_with_comment_count():
    pipeline = [
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "comment",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "post_id",
            "as": "comment_count"
        } },
        { "$addFields": {
            "comment_count": { "$size": "$comment_count" }
        } },
        { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } }
    ]
    posts = list(mongo.db.posts.aggregate(pipeline))

    return posts
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it took me a moment to realise that I needed to pass your code to the template in place of previous query on posts like so;
`return render_template('home.html', posts=posts_with_comment_count(), form=form, admin_user=admin_user())`